# UIView as parent for UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

**What I'm trying to achieve**

nutshell:

use UIView as a container that will move it's "sub-views" when it is moved and also automagically set their visibility when it's visibility changes

long version:

I'd like to have multiple UIImageView within a UIView, whenever UIView is visible, all `UIImageView` are visible, when `UIView` is hidden, all `UIImageView` are hidden, when `UIView` changes position, all `UIImageView` will preserve position within their `UIView` parent.

**Additional Info**

I'm creating a `UIView` dynamically and also a few `UIImageView` which I was hoping that `[UIView addSubview:UIImageViewInstance];` would take care of that, unfortunately, it doesn't.

I'm **not** using the interface builder!

**Question**

how can I achieve above said? If you believe that `UIView` is not the correct way to solve my problem, feel free to present other option(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, using a `UIView` with `UIImageView` subviews is the right approach, IMO. What you said also should work fine - creating a `UIView`, adding `UIImageView` subviews, then moving the parent view and changing its visibility, etc.

I would recommend using something like this:

```
UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:parent];

//Make a horizontal row of 5 images
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 25, 0, 20, 20)];
    [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    [parent addSubview:imgV];
}

//Then you should be able to do things like this and it will apply to the subviews as well
[parent setCenter:self.view.center];
[parent setAlpha:0.8];
//Etc
```

Comment: thank you sir, I just noticed that I've added the UIImageView to an "overlay" UIView, basically, the hierarchy is UIView -> UIView -> 2 UIImageView -- lost focus and added to the wrong view >.<

Answer (score 1):

Well, the approach that you are taking is just fine. I'll just write down the code for your reference. I am assuming that you are working with an instance of `UIViewController` and you are adding subviews to it.

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:
                                   CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIImageView *childImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
[parentView addSubview:childImageView];
```

This should take care of your issue.